# Custom table for str.translate in Python 3

Tags: python, string, replace

If I run this code:

```
s.translate(str.maketrans({'as': 'dfg', '1234': 'qw'}))
```

I will get:

```
ValueError: string keys in translate table must be of length 1
```

Is there a way to replace multiple characters at once using `str.translate`? Docs says I can use `codecs` for flexible approach, but I can't find out how.

If no, what can be done instead then?

Comment: Define "make it work". You can't create a translation table from that dict. But there are other ways to perform multiple replacements in a string.

Comment: How could an inherently unordered `dict` define a deterministic replacement strategy for multiple, possibly overlapping multi-character patterns?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**. `str.translate` can be used **solely** to replace single characters.
The replacement strings can be of any length, but the *keys* must be a single character.

---

When they documentation mentions `codecs` they are saying that you can implement a custom encoding, register it and then open the file using it... it's not a matter of calling something like `codecs.maketrans`, it's quite some work. I'd personally use `re.sub` with a function replacement:

```
replacements = {'as': 'dfg', '1234': 'qw'}
re.sub('({})'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, replacements.keys()))), lambda m: replacements[m.group()], text)
```

Which seems to do what you want:

```
>>> re.sub('({})'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, replacements.keys()))), lambda m: replacements[m.group()], "test as other test1234")
'test dfg other testqw'
```

Comment: What if we have a list of dictionaries as ```replacement```?

Comment: What if we have ```replacements= [{'a': 'b'}, {'23': 'yu'}]```

Answer (score 1):

The `translate` method of a string replaces **one** character by a string according to the translation that you provide.

Here are a few cases:

```
Original string: as 1234
Error in [s.translate(str.maketrans({'as': 'dfg', '1234': 'qw'}))]
Error in [s = s.translate(str.maketrans({'a': 'd', '12': 'q'}))]
s.translate(str.maketrans({'a': 'd', '1': 'q'})): ds q234
```

**Workaround to get the result**

After the edit of the question, here is a solution to get the desired replacements:

Split by the keys, and then join by the values in your translation dictionary.

```
Replaced all subsrings: dfg qw
```

The code:

```
s = 'as 1234'
print('Original string:',s)
try:
    w = s.translate(str.maketrans({'as': 'dfg', '1234': 'qw'}))
    print("s.translate(str.maketrans({'as': 'dfg', '1234': 'qw'}):", w)
except:
    print("Error in [s.translate(str.maketrans({'as': 'dfg', '1234': 'qw'}))]")
try:   
    w = s.translate(str.maketrans({'a': 'd', '12': 'q'}))
    print("s.translate(str.maketrans({'a': 'd', '12': 'q'})):", w)
except:
    print("Error in [s = s.translate(str.maketrans({'a': 'd', '12': 'q'}))]")
try:   
    w = s.translate(str.maketrans({'a': 'd', '1': 'q'}))
    print("s.translate(str.maketrans({'a': 'd', '1': 'q'})):", w)
except:
    print("Error in [s = s.translate(str.maketrans({'a': 'd', '1': 'q'}))]")

trans_dict = {'as': 'dfg', '1234': 'qw'}
for k,v in trans_dict.items():
    y = s.split(k)
    s = v.join(y)
print('Replaced all subsrings:',s)
```